# gson.fromJson() method converting invalid json to valid json

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, gson

In my program i am taking input from rest client in json format and retrieving the json from request body i am using gson.fromJson method for retrieving json.

```
BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson( reader , JsonElement.class );
```

Input json, i am passing to rest client : 
It is not a valid json.

```
{
"buildName":FHGF"",
"deadline":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00",
"release":"0.2",
"platformRelease":"5.10.0",
"platformBuild":"1.0.0",
"releatedProducts":"##Product*****",
"expiresInPronto":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00",
"changeNotesRequired":"yes",
"environment":"ah",
"stateTestedInUse":"no"
}
```

Json which is created by gson :

```
 {
    **"buildName":"FHGF\"\""**,
    "deadline":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00",
    "release":"0.2",
    "platformRelease":"5.10.0",
    "platformBuild":"1.0.0",
    "releatedProducts":"##Product*****",
    "expiresInPronto":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00",
    "changeNotesRequired":"yes",
    "environment":"ah",
    "stateTestedInUse":"no"
}
```

Instead of throwing error gson has converted it to valid json.

Comment: Can you please specify the problem?

Comment: on using gson.fromJson i am giving invalid json but Instead of throwing error gson has converted it to valid json.

Comment: Json I have passed : {"buildName":FHGF"","deadline":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00","release":"0.2","platformRelease":"5.10.0","platformBuild":"1.0.0","releatedProducts":"##Product*****","expiresInPronto":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00","changeNotesRequired":"yes","environment":"ah","stateTestedInUse":"no"}

Comment: Json created by gson : {"buildName":"FHGF\"\"","deadline":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00","release":"0.2","platformRelease":"5.10.0","platformBuild":"1.0.0","releatedProducts":"##Product*****","expiresInPronto":"2017-07-28T23:11:15+00:00","changeNotesRequired":"yes","environment":"ah","stateTestedInUse":"no"}